# How to keep values for nonexistent categories while subtracting dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 12 dataframes with cumulative values, and I want to transform them to non-cumulative one.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "ADMIN": [1, 2],
    "FIN_SOURCE": ["A", "B"],
    "PROG": [150, 155],
    "FUNC": [1, 2],
    "ECON": [30, 50],
    "VALUE": [5, 10]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "ADMIN": [1, 2, 1],
    "FIN_SOURCE": ["A", "B", "A"],
    "PROG": [150, 155, 160],
    "FUNC": [1, 2, 1],
    "ECON": [30, 50, 50],
    "VALUE": [10, 15, 50]
})
```

Each dataset has columns pointing to different categories (`ADMIN`, `FIN_SOURCE`, `PROG`, `FUNC`, `ECON`), and for dataset+1 there are more unique values within each category.

What I tried to do:

```py
indxs = ["ADMIN", "FIN_SOURCE", "PROG", "FUNC", "ECON"]
(df2.set_index(indxs) - df1.set_index(indxs)).reset_index()

    ADMIN   FIN_SOURCE  PROG    FUNC    ECON    VALUE
0   1       A           150     1       30      5.0
1   1       A           160     1       50      NaN    #<- I want to keep it as 50 (value in df2 before sub)
2   2       B           155     2       50      5.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) with `fill_value=0` parameter:

```
indxs = ["ADMIN", "FIN_SOURCE", "PROG", "FUNC", "ECON"]
df = df2.set_index(indxs).sub(df1.set_index(indxs), fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
   ADMIN FIN_SOURCE  PROG  FUNC  ECON  VALUE
0      1          A   150     1    30    5.0
1      1          A   160     1    50   50.0
2      2          B   155     2    50    5.0
```